# How to report sites on AdBlock 1.8.8 for Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, adblock

I'm using:

- Chrome Version 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit)
- Adblock Plus 1.8.8
- OS X 10.10.2 (14C78c)

I found [a site that has an ad not blocked by Adblock Plus](https://www.wiknix.com/your-profile-cannot-be-used-in-google-chrome/).

According to [the FAQ](https://adblockplus.org/en/getting_started) I should be able to report an issue using a screen like this:

> [image: Report issue on this page menu]

However, in my browser, all I see is this:

> [image]

The UI is pretty different from the screenshot. How do I access "Report issue on this page…" in the current version of Adblock Plus?

Comment: In my opinion, you should just block element, and it will be reported automatically. However, your first menu appears from bottom of the screen and second is the standard menu which appears when you click on ABP button inside the toolbar. May be this is the issue.

Comment: @Danatela Is it documented that blocking an element will automatically report it? I don't see a menu on the bottom of the screen, only one to the right of the address bar.

Comment: You can still report it at the [EasyList forums](http://forums.lanik.us/index.php).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this forum post](https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=26600):

> That feature is only available in Firefox and related browsers.

There's a [related ticket from 6 months ago](https://issues.adblockplus.org/ticket/688) to add this info to the FAQ, but it looks like nobody's gotten around to it yet.

Comment: Yep, I noticed that report window in FAQ has firefox icon and started it to be sure.